# Android SurfaceView - Some paths render in delay when panning or zooming

Tags: android, performance, 2d, android-canvas, surfaceview

I've implemented some kind of a vector map using Android's SurfaceView and a Canvas.
Each element of the map is represented by a path that is being drawn in a for loop that draws each path onto the canvas.

Something like this -

```
void doDraw(Canvas canvas)
        {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

        if (mMapModel == null)
            return;

        for (MapElement e : mMapModel.getMapElements()){
            Path[] drawing = e.getDraw();
            canvas.drawPath(drawing[0], mPathFramePaint);   //draw the frame
            mPathFillPaint.setColor(e.color);
            canvas.drawPath(drawing[1], mPathFillPaint);    //draw the fill
}
```

The problem I'm having is that there's a really weird "drifting" behavior each time I pan the map. It seems like some of the elements are rendered in a delay that causes them to appear in their previous location rather than in their new real location.

You can see the phenomena in this video -

[Video on YouTube](http://youtu.be/6XpgS1ft0KI)

I'm trying to figure out if maybe there's something I'm not doing right. I doesn't seem to me like it's such a heavy thing to do that should cause items to render too late.

This the the code that the background thread is running -

```
public class MapViewThread extends Thread

{

    boolean mRun;

    Canvas mcanvas;

    SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;

    Context context;

    MapView mMapView;



    public MapViewThread(SurfaceHolder sholder, Context ctx, MapView mapView)
    {
        surfaceHolder = sholder;

        context = ctx;

        mRun = false;

        mMapView = mapView;

    }

    void setRunning(boolean bRun)
    {
        mRun = bRun;
    }


    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        super.run();
        while(mRun)
        {
            mcanvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
            if(mcanvas != null) 
            {
                mMapView.doDraw(mcanvas);

                surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(mcanvas);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try Thread.sleep(60); in the onTouch method.

Comment: Hey Leco, Thanks for the suggestion! I added Thread.Sleep(60) to the onTouch method, it did improve some of the glitches, but now when I pan, some of the paths flicker for a split second on every zoom/pan. It also caused panning to be less smooth. Any Other suggestion?

Comment: Can you post your pan code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved it. It was a threading issue!

On each pan I'm iterating on a big list of paths and update each path's coordinates.

The rendering thread was rendering my paths before I was able to finish update the position of each item in the list.

With some synchronization I between the two threads I was able to solve this.